# Comparar STRINGS con IF

Tags: java, string, condiciones, jdeveloper

Simplemente quiero extraer un **String** de *jTextField1* ubicado en un **jFrame** llamado **BaseDatos** desde otro **jFrame** para ejecutar una instrucción IF que me muestre un mensaje dependiendo quien se está conectando, pero siempre me muestra como que la condición es FALSA.

```
import app.BaseDatos;            

String uu=BaseDatos.jTextField1.getText();
        if(uu=="root"){
            ultimoMensajeMySQL="Conexión realizada! Bienvenid@.\nHa ingresado al sistema como ADMINISTRADOR ("+uu+").";
        }else{
            ultimoMensajeMySQL="Conexión realizada! Bienvenid@.\nHas ingresado al sistema como USUARIO ("+uu+").";
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: usa `equals` para comparar String `if(uu.equals("root")`

Comment: @Dramaturgo muchas gracias!!